# Accessing Outlook's Status Bar from a VSTO Add-In

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have my VSTO Add-In functioning as desired, thanks to many here on SO.  It turns out, visual feedback would be a good thing - how can I customize the Outlook status bar from my Add-In to show messages/icons/whatever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any property or method for customizing the status bar. Instead, you may consider adding your own form. Microsoft calls such foms as *adjacent*. See [Adjacent Windows In Outlook](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephen_griffin/archive/2010/06/01/adjacent-windows-in-outlook.aspx) for more information. Also you may find a sample project in C++ which illustrates the required steps to get it working in Outlook - [Creating Adjacent Windows In Outlook](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-Adjacent-Windows-00090e4a).

Finally, you may find [Advanced Outlook view and form regions](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/outlook-regions-basics.php) helpful. There is no need to subclass Outlook windows in that case. All is done by Add-in Express for you.